# Solve the recurrence $T(n)=T(n-2)+\frac{1}{\lg{n}}$

Tags: recurrence-relation

Assume this recurrence:
$$T(n)=T(n-2)+\frac{1}{\lg{n}}$$
I tried to draw its recurrence tree and I reached that the whole cost is $\dfrac{1}{\lg{n}}+\dfrac{1}{\lg{n-2}}+\dots+\dfrac{1}{x}$ that $x$ is $2$ if $n$ is even, otherwise is $3$. So somehow we should solve $\sum_{i=1}^{\frac{n}{2}}{\dfrac{1}{\lg{2i}}}$ or $\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}{\dfrac{1}{\lg{2i+1}}}$ that both equal to the same $\Theta(f(n))$. I read somewhere that it equals $\Theta(\dfrac{n}{\lg{n}})$, but I can't find out how. The lower bound is easy, but what about the upper bound?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring rounding (which does not affect the asymptotic growth rate):
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n/2} \frac{1}{\log 2i} \ge
\sum_{i=1}^{n/2} \frac{1}{\log n} \ge
\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{n}{\log n} = \Omega\Big(\frac{n}{\log n}\Big),
$$
and

$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n/2} \frac{1}{\log 2i} &=
\sum_{i=1}^{\sqrt{n}/2} \frac{1}{\log 2i}  + \sum_{i=\sqrt{n}/2}^{n/2} \frac{1}{\log 2i} 
\le  \sqrt{n} +  \frac{n}{\log \sqrt{n}} \\
& = O(\sqrt{n}) + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{n}{\log n} = O\Big(\frac{n}{\log n}\Big).
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Every recursion formula of the form $T(n) = T(n-k) + f(n)$ for sum fixed $k$ can be turned into a sum: $T(n)$ is the sum of $f(n - i\times k)$ for those $i$ where $f(n - i\times k)$ is not known, plus the first known value. In your case you would need to know $T(1)$ and $T(0)$ without the recursion formula.

Note that for $\sqrt n ≤ j ≤ n$ we have $(\log j) / 2 ≤ \log j ≤ \log n$.